# Scroll event: same behavior on different resolutions

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, screen-resolution

I have a webpage that fires some events (specifically, fading in/out some elements) when user scrolls X pixels.

Everything works fine on 1920x1080p resolution or like landscape resolutions (fine on iPhone 5 landscape for exampe). The problem is with larger resolutions or vertical res because content is already available without scrolling so the events are not fired.

How can I have a consistent behavior with all resolutions?
Is there a way that allows me not to use media queries?

Here's a video of the events firing at 1920x1080p when scrolling:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mtuy1E5JPew

And here's the **[link](http://ffio.it/longobardi/index3.html)** of the webpage.

Here's one example of the script to fade in/out an element based on how much the user scrolled:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $logopiano = $('#logopiano');

function showHideLogo() {
   if( $window.scrollTop() > 910 ) {
        $logopiano.fadeIn("slow", function() {
        });
   } else {
        $logopiano.fadeOut("slow", function() {
        });
   }
}

showHideLogo();
$window.scroll(showHideLogo);
```

Comment: It's bad practice to post duplicates of the same question, add the code you're having issues with into your question [either one]. you'll be more likely to recieve an answer.

Comment: It's not the same question. This tackles the jQuery script to fade in/out events when scrolling and how to properly address different resolutions . The other tackles how the B/W image should move (fixed positioning but content below should cover it when scrolling).

Comment: no problem at all man, my bad.

Comment: Ok.. I'm always worried I explained the questions badly because my english is not perfect..

Comment: Your formatting of the questions and english is fine, you just need to add code. no one can help [easily] you without code.

Comment: Yep, added one of the snippets I use to fade in/out the elements

Comment: The events are fired, you just do not have 910 pixels available to scroll..

Comment: I know.. :D Still a problem :(
Maybe mixing the position with onmousewheel and keydown..? If user has reached the end of the page, rely on onmousewheel and keydown

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the scroll handler at the beginning. (*right after binding the scroll handler*)

```
$window.scroll(showHideLogo).trigger('scroll');
```

---

Update, on second thought, since you test the scroll position and not where the element you want is, this will not work.

Try checking if you reached the bottom

```
function showHideLogo() {
   var availableScroll = $(document).height() - $window.height(),
       scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

   if( scrollTop > 910 || scrollTop  == availableScroll) {
        $logopiano.fadeIn("slow", function() {
        });
   } else {
        $logopiano.fadeOut("slow", function() {
        });
   }
}
```

(*but you will have to manually make sure the elements align, as i see that you want to position it at a specific place*)

Comment: Now with larger resolutions the elements are shown by default:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j25mssehv542lsf/Screenshot%202015-05-10%2002.19.18.png?dl=0

Here's a live example: http://ffio.it/longobardi/index4.html

Comment: Yes maybe it's the simpler solution. and on mobile I can make all the elements visible by default to simplify my life :). Is there a way to consistently position the braille? Because right now I'm using http://pastebin.com/XD6tteM6 to "stop" the position:fixed at a certain px but now with larger (but not so large to not have to scroll at all) resolutions it's not positioned in the space I want it to be..

Comment: Maybe not using followTo(880) but counting the height of the elements below and using END OF THE PAGE minus THAT HEIGHT to position the braille image correctly..?